# NVD3.js yAxis and tooltip different percision

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm using NVD3.js to display a multi-line chart.

I would like the yAxis to display to 2 decimal numbers

*edited answer*

```
 var chart;

    nv.addGraph(function () {
        chart = nv.models.lineChart()
        .options({
            margin: { left: 140, bottom: 50 },
            x: function (d, i) {
                return i;
            },
            showXAxis: true,
            showYAxis: true,
            transitionDuration: 250,
            tooltips: true,
            tooltipContent: function (key, x, y, e, graph) {
                return '<h3>' + key + '</h3>' +
                       '<p>' + e.point.y + ' at ' + x + '</p>'
            }
        });

        // chart sub-models (ie. xAxis, yAxis, etc) when accessed directly, return themselves, not the parent chart, so need to chain separately
        chart.xAxis
            .axisLabel("Maturity")
            .tickFormat(function(d) { return pivotedData[0].values[d].x; });

        chart.yAxis
            .axisLabel('Model Spread').tickFormat(d3.format(',.2f'));


        d3.select('#chart1 svg')
          .datum(pivotedData)
          .call(chart);

        //TODO: Figure out a good way to do this automatically
        nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

        chart.dispatch.on('stateChange', function (e) { nv.log('New State:', JSON.stringify(e)); });

        return chart;
    });
```

But in the tool tip on the lines i would like to display to 12 decimals places.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the function that is called to format the contents of a tooltip through `.tooltipContent` of the chart object. The default function is defined as follows.

```
tooltip = function(key, x, y, e, graph) {
    return '<h3>' + key + '</h3>' +
           '<p>' +  y + ' at ' + x + '</p>'
}
```

You can format the value of `y` in there to your liking. Note that `y` is defined as

```
yAxis.tickFormat()(lines.y()(e.point, e.pointIndex))
```

This means that the tick formatting for the axis will affect it, so in order to achieve a higher precision there, you need to get the value directly -- `lines` can be accessed through `chart.lines`.

Comment: i did try editing that function and it had no effect on the tooltip

Comment: Are you using the latest version of NVD3 (from the source repository)? Which chart type are you using?

Comment: yes, i pulled it yesterday and i'm i'm using the lineChart model. chart = nv.models.lineChart()

Comment: Should be working then. Can you show us the complete code please?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff - I was under the assumption that once the  data is formatted using `.tickFormat(d3.format(',.2f'))` to 2 decimal places the chart uses that applied formatting of data through out the chart, even when the data is displayed in the tooltip. So is it possible to display 12 decimals places in the tooltip using `y`

Comment: edited my post. i edited the lineChart tooltip function and also tried added the function to the options arguments without any luck.

Comment: I'll update the answer with respect to the formatting. I don't see where you're modifying the tooltip function in the code you've posted though.

Comment: i initially edited LineChart.js and i also tried this *see updated initial post*, both had no effect.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the function under the key `tooltipContent`?

Answer (score 0):

In the nvd3 source they have lines like so (Line Chart):

```
 interactiveLayer.dispatch.on('elementMousemove', function(e) {
  ...
      var xValue = xAxis.tickFormat()(chart.x()(singlePoint,pointIndex));
      interactiveLayer.tooltip
              .position({left: pointXLocation + margin.left, top: e.mouseY + margin.top})
              ...
              .valueFormatter(function(d,i) {
                 return yAxis.tickFormat()(d);
              })
              .data(
                  {
                    value: xValue,
                    series: allData
                  }
              )();
...
}
```

So if you want to override something like tooltip.contentGenerator you are stuck with the data it gives you.  I think a good way to do this would be to have a setter for tooltip x formatter or something then it will use that over the axis formatter.  Or simply sending over the raw data along with the value and series.

My usecase is that I am showing a timescale of 7 days on the graph I only tick the start of each day.  However on the tooltip I want to give a more detailed view of that data.

Here is my pull request specific to the guidelines tooltip

https://github.com/novus/nvd3/pull/444

Calling: chart.tooltipXAxisFormatter(d3.time.format(toolTipFormat)); will set it.